# How can I manage the state 'call in progress' in an outgoing call?

Tags: java, android, call

I'm italian and my english could be bed, i'm sorry for it.
I want manage the state 'call in progress' in all outgoing call, to explain better I want do some things  (like play music) during the "*TUUU TUUU*" noise you hear before the recipient answers (sorry but I don't know what you call it).

It's possible?

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any change is detected in the call state the of the device,(I assume that you know how to register a listener to listen to call states) call back function - `public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)` is triggered, with the state and incoming number.

Various states are - `CALL_STATE_IDLE`, `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`, and `CALL_STATE_RINGING`

1) IDLE             – when there is no incoming call

2) OFFHOOK   – when the line is busy

3) RINGING      – when call is incoming

The ***"TUUUU TUUUUU"*** sound you are talking about, is the functionality provided by the network provider and you CAN'T do anything related to that.

Comment: so i can't do anything?

Comment: unfortunately, no you can't do anything.